# What is a good open source chat solution?

Tags: java, chat

I'm looking for a free scalable chat solution, sort of the equivalent of SOLR but for chat. I have a LAMP application that I need to integrate the chat with. For search I'm using SOLR and since it has a REST interface integrating with it was easy and didn't require writing any Java.

Is there a similar ready made solution that's also high peformance for chat?
Obviously MySQL/PHP/AJAX based periodic polling scripts are out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with a good jabber implementation.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/index.jsp

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp

Comment: Yes I also recommend implementations which is based on famous XMPP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

http://jwebsocket.org/
They have a chat demo you can download and modify (it is licensed under LGPL).
I'm developing a facebook-like chat with Node.js, it's not so difficult and works great. I'm using "socket.io" and now I'm going to develop an android app too, with https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client
Do you need private chat? or only public? Igniterealtime as @krishnakumarp posted seems much more complex and complete.

Comment: thanks, will look into this. Atm I need just 1 on 1 but eventually would need to add support for group chats as well.